# Does Tokens Regex have support for dependency annotations?

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am building a rule based NER platform and wanted to know if I could make use of dependency based patterns to identify named entities. E.g

> CYLD inhibits the ubiquititnation of both TRAF2 and TRAF6.

Here I could use a `prep_of` relation/pattern to identify proteins TRAF2 and TRAF6 with the trigger being ubiquitination.(as mentioned in the Odin's Runes research paper).

If TokensRegex does support dependency annotations could anyone please share an example of how its implemented in the rules file? I will be ever grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Naively no. But, you could work around this by attaching custom annotations to your `CoreLabel`s; e.g., have an annotation for the incoming dependency arc. Then, you can have a TokensRegex pattern over this custom annotation key.